# Unix moment fromNow in local time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a unix timestamp from server. How can I display a fromNow in the user's local time?

```js
var dateTime = 1470953907000;

$("div:first").text(moment(dateTime).format("lll") + " - " + moment(dateTime).fromNow());
$("div:last").text(moment.utc(dateTime).format("lll") + " - " + moment.utc(dateTime).fromNow());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: What's a UTC timestamp? Do you mean a Unix timestamp?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean!

Comment: Maybe this one: moment.utc(dateTime).fromNow().toDate().toLocaleTimeString();

Comment: What is the issue with your first example? As th doc says [_By default, moment parses and displays in local time_](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) and you first example in my timezone (`Europe/Rome`) now (`2016-08-12 12:52`) shows `Aug 11, 2016 10:18 PM - 13 hours ago`.

Comment: Why would time zone matter for `fromNow`?  It is just a relative delta between two points on a universal timeline.  What are you actually looking for?